# How to disable keyboard shortcuts info dialog in ubuntu when super key is pressed?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation, hotkeys, ubuntu-unity

How to disable it please? It behaves buggy when using vmware workstation virtual machines. Randomly appearing on the screen or when minimizing vmware... It would be great if I could disable that dialog.

Check this image if you don't know what dialog I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of approaches exits,a few was given by the time the 12.04 was the highest version, but you please try though on your 14.04 or whatever (I didn't check everything on every version):

- For those like me that prefer the command line:

### Ubuntu 12.04 and below:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/shortcut_overlay --type bool false
```

### Ubuntu 12.10+:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/shortcut-overlay false
```

## For Ubuntu 12.04 and below:

The *keyboard shortcut overlay* is controlled by an option in the compiz unity plugin.

[image]

In the experimental tab of `ccsm` you can untick the option shown.

Remember the use of CCSM is strongly discouraged - you can achieve the same via `gconf-editor`

[image]

untick the option shown in the path `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/shortcut_overlay`

## For Ubuntu 12.10:

You can disable this behavior following this steps:

1. [Install **Ubuntu Tweak**](https://askubuntu.com/q/75454/62483) [image: Install-It]
2. Open the label *Tweaks* and choice *Unity*

   [image: screenshoot]
3. Now you have to look at the second option called *Shortcuts hints overlay*

   [image: screenshoot2]
4. Now click at the box to turn this feature off, so this remains as this:

   [image: screenshoot3]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have ubuntu 14.04 and this command totally worked lol, thanks

`dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/shortcut-overlay false`